# Return model method in JSON hash with an :include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, activerecord, include

I've got an active record query which is pretty simple

```
def show
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  render :text => user.to_json(:include=>:classes)
end
```

However, in my `Class` model, I have a method

```
def self.get_avg_prev_score(id)
  return Scores.calc_score(id)
end
```

I am trying to get the `avg_prev_score` returned in my JSON hash, but seeing as it isn't a column in the database, I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to return an average previous score for each of the classes you're including, you could do:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  render :text => JSON::parse(@user.to_json(:include=>:classes)).merge("avg_prev_scores" => @user.get_avg_prev_scores_for_classes).to_json
end
```

and then have your other method return a hash of all scores correlated to the `class_id`:

```
# User.rb model
def get_avg_prev_scores_for_classes
  average_scores = []
  self.classes.each {|c| average_scores << [c.id, Scores.calc_score(c.id)]}
  return Hash[*average_scores.flatten]
end
```

Comment: I think you are very close, but the problem is the id used in Scores isn't the user id, so not self.id, it's the class id, and the user doesn't know the class ids. It also feels a bit strange to be calling the average score for the class from the user. I tried calling classes.id, as a user has many classes, not class, but that didn't work either. I think you're very close though, and thanks for editing my question, I asked it horribly, I apologize.

Comment: I updated my answer with what you can do.  I am assuming that you want to return all average scores for each class the user is associated with, so I am returning a hash that is structured as: `class_id => calculated_score`

Comment: I'm not just getting an simple average, I've got a few things going on in that function. the `some_id` is coming from the users classes, so each user has many classes, each class has many scores. I'm thinking I may need to map the class_ids and then merge afterward. Does that makes sense?? Sounds difficult to me.

Comment: @pedalpete See my updated answer first (just updated it a few minutes ago)

Comment: This is SSSSOOO close, I've almost got it thanks to your help. The only difference is that it doesn't make sense to have the scores seperate from the other class details, so I changed the code to `self.classes.each{|c| c['avg_scores']=[Scores.calc_score(c.id)]}` the only problem is that now I have two `classes` hashes in the output, the one with the scores, and the one without. Is it possible to over-write the original classes? or just append the Score to the original class? I'm ending up with two classes hashes in the output.

Comment: Just merge the two together into one hash

Comment: phew, that took a while, but I got it. Thanks for your help. In my controller I now have `render :text => JSON::parse(@user.to_json(:include=>:classes)).merge("classes" => @user.get_avg_prev_scores_for_classes).to_json`, I didn't know that just naming the `avg_prev_scores` to `classes` would merge them properly. thanks

Comment: Glad to help!!  Best of luck to you!